# Parsing XML using XMLReader + SimpleXML in PHP

Tags: php, xml-parsing, simplexml, xmlreader

Recently I got from [here](http://posterous.richardcunningham.co.uk/using-a-hybrid-of-xmlreader-and-simplexml) about how to parse large xml files using of XMLReader and SimpleXML in PHP. I tried to adapt the code of above mentioned tutorial into my php procedure like this:

```
$xml_url = "http://localhost/rest/server.php?wstoken=".$token&function=contents";
    $reader = new XMLReader;
    $reader->open($xml_url);

    while($reader->read()){
        if($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $reader->name == 'SINGLE'){
            $doc = new DOMDocument('1.0','UTF-8');
            $xml = simplexml_import_dom($doc->importNode($reader->expand(), true));
            //$titleString = (string) $xml->description;
            echo $xml->description;
        }
    }
```

The XML file called via url is so (the xml version is [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/72519118/response.xml)):
[image: screenshot]

Other SINGLE tags (marked with 'red') have the same structure and I want to print 'description' of them also.

The output is with above mentioned php procedure is: error on line 1 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document. Any help would be great.

Comment: Can't you simply use `simplexml_load_file` and xpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`SimpleXML`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php) function should be enough:

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file('http://dl.dropbox.com/u/72519118/response.xml');
var_dump($xml->xpath('//SINGLE/KEY[@name="description"]/VALUE/text()'));
```

The above `var_dump` outputs:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1703) "<div class="no-overflow">..."
  }
  [1]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (1) {
    [0]=>
    string(9906) "<div class="no-overflow">..."
  }
  [2]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (1) {
    [0]=>
    string(4114) "<div class="no-overflow">..."
  }
}
```

Note that tag names in `xpath()` is case sensitive, so `'//single/key...'` doesn't work.

**Addition**:

The "standard" way to retrieve text value in SimpleXML is `$KEY->VALUE`;

However if you have reached the "end" node of the XML tree (like I do in my XPath), you can simply type-cast it to string to get the value:

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file('http://dl.dropbox.com/u/72519118/response.xml');
$result=$xml->xpath('//SINGLE/KEY[@name="description"]/VALUE/text()');
foreach($result as $text)
{
    var_dump((string)$text);
}
```

The above outputs:

```
string(1703) "<div class="no-overflow"><p>..."
string(9906) "<div class="no-overflow"><h3>..."
string(4114) "<div class="no-overflow"><h3>..."
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, i used it, but the result is now : error on line 1 at column 1: Document is empty

Comment: @Dozent I tried this code again and still get the same result. Are you sure your `server.php` generates the same valid XML as you post on DropBox?

Comment: yes now it's works, i was mistakenly put Content-type: application/xml rather than text/html. The result is now:

array(15) {
  [0]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (0) {
  }
  [1]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (0) {
  }
  [2]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (0) {
...

to be honest I don't know how to extract values from this set of arrays. Can you show me the approach? Thanks